# I have created a measure in power BI which is sum of minutes. How do i convert it to HH:MM:SS format

Tags: powerbi

I have defined a measure as

```
Measure = sum('Combined FL'[login hours (Minutes)])
```

How do I convert the minutes to `HH:MM:SS` format?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this measure:

```
Formatted Duration (HH:MM:SS) = 
VAR _mins = SUM ( 'Combined FL'[login hours (Minutes)] )
VAR _hrs = QUOTIENT(_mins, 60)
VAR _min = MOD(_mins, 60)
RETURN FORMAT(_hrs, "00") &":"& FORMAT(_min, "00") & ":00"
```